# Cartesian Product resulting in List of List of fixed length (the haskell way)

Tags: haskell

I want to create a sequence of elements ([0, 1]) of fixed length (e.g. 4) such that it results in a list of lists of elements containing all combinations of [0,1].

I solved it using an imperative programming approach:

```
Prelude > let base = [1, 0]
Prelude > [[x0, x1, x2, x3] | x0 <- base, x1 <- base, x2 <- base, x3 <- base]
[[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0],[1,1,0,1], ... [0,0,0,0]]
```

which I think is improvable.

What is the idiomatic way of doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sequence` works:

```
Prelude> sequence (replicate 4 [1,0])
[[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0],[1,1,0,1],[1,1,0,0],[1,0,1,1],[1,0,1,0],[1,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0],[0,1,1,1],[0,1,1,0],[0,1,0,1],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,1],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,0]]
```

But the pairing of sequence and replicate already has a name:

```
Prelude> import Control.Monad
Prelude Control.Monad> replicateM 4 [1,0]
[[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0],[1,1,0,1],[1,1,0,0],[1,0,1,1],[1,0,1,0],[1,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0],[0,1,1,1],[0,1,1,0],[0,1,0,1],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,1],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,0]]
```

Since `sequence` is doing all the interesting work, let's take a closer look at it.

```
sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]
sequence [] = return []
sequence (x:xs) = do
    x'  <- x
    xs' <- sequence xs
    return (x':xs')
```

(There are shorter ways to write that, but this is the most straightforward.)

It turns out `sequence` doesn't contain any of the interesting logic either.  That's the only obvious function with that type signature that uses the entirety of its argument. So the real magic must be in the `Monad` instance for `[]`, I guess.

```
instance Monad [] where
    return x = [x]
    xs >>= f = concatMap f xs
```

This just passes the buck to `concatMap` - but maybe it's starting to make more sense now..

```
concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]
concatMap _ [] = []
concatMap f (x:xs) = f x ++ concatMap f xs
```

I'm not sure how much all that helps, but it's worth keeping in mind.

Possibly more helpful is to specialize the type signature of `sequence` to `m ~ []`:

```
sequence :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
```

In this specific case, `sequence` might actually be better renamed to `sequences`. It creates all the sequences that consist of choosing one element from each inner list.

Comment: Ha, I knew there is a Haskell way, thank you! Could you tell me as well why we require a Monad here?

Comment: @Robin Well, `[]` is already an instance of `Monad`. Hard to solve a list problem without lists. As for the import of `Control.Monad`, it's just because that's where `replicateM` is kept.

Comment: thank you. It seems I need to read some more chapters about Monads.